# Pulling JSON data into PHP7 (Notice: Trying to get property of non-object)

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to pull the following JSON data into php variables.

```
{"links":[],"content":{"carrier":{"allowedToOperate":"Y","bipdInsuranceOnFile":"0","bipdInsuranceRequired":"N","bipdRequiredAmount":"0","bondInsuranceOnFile":"75","bondInsuranceRequired":"Y","brokerAuthorityStatus":"A","cargoInsuranceOnFile":"0","cargoInsuranceRequired":"N","carrierOperation":{"carrierOperationCode":"A","carrierOperationDesc":"Interstate"},"commonAuthorityStatus":"N","contractAuthorityStatus":"N","crashTotal":0,"dbaName":null,"dotNumber":2230336,"driverInsp":0,"driverOosInsp":0,"driverOosRate":0,"driverOosRateNationalAverage":"5.51","ein":null,"fatalCrash":0,"hazmatInsp":0,"hazmatOosInsp":0,"hazmatOosRate":0,"hazmatOosRateNationalAverage":"4.5","injCrash":0,"isPassengerCarrier":"N","issScore":null,"legalName":"BAY TRANSPORTATION SERVICES LLC","oosDate":null,"oosRateNationalAverageYear":"2009-2010","phone":"9897559445","phyCity":"AUBURN","phyCountry":"US","phyState":"MI","phyStreet":"4030 GARFIELD ROAD, SUITE 200","phyZipcode":"48611","reviewDate":null,"reviewType":null,"safetyRating":null,"safetyRatingDate":null,"safetyReviewDate":null,"safetyReviewType":null,"snapshotDate":"1464321600000","statusCode":"A","totalDrivers":0,"totalPowerUnits":0,"towawayCrash":0,"vehicleInsp":0,"vehicleOosInsp":0,"vehicleOosRate":0,"vehicleOosRateNationalAverage":"20.72"},"links":[{"rel":"basics","href":"http://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/2230336/basics"},{"rel":"cargo carried","href":"http://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/2230336/cargo-carried"},{"rel":"operation classification","href":"http://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/2230336/operation-classification"},{"rel":"docket numbers","href":"http://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/2230336/docket-numbers"},{"rel":"carrier active-For-hire authority","href":"http://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/2230336/authority"},{"rel":"self","href":"http://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/2230336"}]}}
```

This is the code im running minus the APIKEY

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$GETdotnum = $_GET["dot"];
function curl_request($sURL,$sQueryString=null)
{
    $cURL=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($cURL,CURLOPT_URL,$sURL.'?'.$sQueryString);
    curl_setopt($cURL,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $cResponse=trim(curl_exec($cURL));
    curl_close($cURL);
    return $cResponse;
}

$sResponse=curl_request('https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/' . $GETdotnum, 'webkey=APIKEY');
$oJSON=json_decode($sResponse);
if ($oJSON->content->carrier->allowedToOperate=='Y')
{
    $CarrierName=$oJSON->content->carrier->legalName;
    $CarrierAddress=$oJSON->content->carrier->phyStreet;
    $CarrierPhoneNumber=$oJSON->content->carrier->phone;
}
else
echo $oJSON;
echo "Error: Carrier Operate Status: " . $oJSON->content->carrier->allowedToOperate;
```

These are the errors im receiving

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/sirmikey/public_html/fmcsa.php on line 17

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/sirmikey/public_html/fmcsa.php on line 17

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/sirmikey/public_html/fmcsa.php on line 24

Comment: `var_dump($oJSON, $oJSON->content, $oJSON->content->carrier)`

Comment: could you add a `var_dump($oJSON);` just after `$oJSON=json_decode($sResponse);`? does it displays the object?

Comment: `$oJSON` does not seems a valid object. Have you check if `$oJson` is not false? Try using `json_last_error_msg()` to see if `json_decode` method works as expected

Comment: @rap-2-h
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["links"]=> array(0) { } ["content"]=> string(192) "[Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null" }

Comment: Your URL is probably not constructed properly.  Maybe missing a `/` or a `?`.  `echo` it and compare to what the API requires.

Comment: just a guess, consider `'/webkey....'`

Comment: @Whiteulver No Error

Comment: This is your error in the JSON `["content"]=> string(192) "[Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null"`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Correct that is what i get if I try to echo the URL or run var_dump

Comment: it might be a stupid question, but do you actually have an apikey and do you actually use it? because it seems like your request was denied and so we probably can't say anything about the code ...

Comment: @Jakumi yes i do and when i type the URL into the browser with the key I get the response I gave in the first post

Comment: with first post you mean your first comment or the question? because if it's the comment, then this might say, that your request is just invalid and you have to fix it. check that you're actually requesting the correct url

Comment: @jakumi The question

Comment: Go ahead and try it yourself... I'll change the key after its fixed.
webkey=ab2a3c1bc4d78600d0375e9a8d985887a58ad2d8

Comment: what is `$_GET["dot"]` ?  otherwise I can't check ;o/

Comment: Sorry
GETdotnum = 2230336

Comment: https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/2230336?webkey=ab2a3c1bc4d78600d0375e9a8d985887a58ad2d8 produces an error. so it possibly is an error in the url you're requesting ...

Comment: Gosh darn case sensitive.... Its working.. God I feel stupid. Thanks alot guys